# Android checking radio button in code makes it stay checked in a radiogroup

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I have a dynamically added radio buttons in a `RadioGroup`. And I have to check one of them in code based on some data.

Now, the issue is after the radio buttons are shown and the user checks on another radio button in the same group, the previously selected radio is still checked ... resulting in two checked `RadioButtons`.

[image: Radio buttons with one of them that can't be unchecked]

This is how I am rendering the buttons in Kotlin:

```
val rg = RadioGroup(this).apply { orientation = RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL }
choices.values.forEach { c ->
    rg.addView(RadioButton(this).apply {
        tag = someTag
        text = c
        isChecked = answer.equals(c) // condition
    })
}
```

The strange thing is it all works fine if no `RadioButton` is checked programmatically.

Comment: Are you using the kotlin-kapt plugin? (Just so I know what to use in my answer)

Comment: @AnthonyCannon No. Just plain kotlin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of setting `radioButton.isChecked = ...`. Try using the `radioGroup.check(id)`.

Comment: Thanks man. The `index` in `radioGroup.check` call is rather the radio button `Id`. In addition to that, I had to do the `radioGroup.check(index)` call after adding all the radio buttons.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Ill update my answer. Glad I can help.

Comment: my bad, I was doing `radioButton.isSelected = ... ` It is isChecked instead

Answer (score 4):

I use this code for RadioButton.

```
radio_rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
    val radio: RadioButton = findViewById(checkedId)
    when (radio) {
        radioBtn1 -> {
            // some code
        }
        radioBtn2 -> {
             // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

About no RadioButton being checked, I've never tried it.